# Why my ubuntu freezes while copying or extracting 2+ GB files

Tags: hard-drive, freeze, disk, storage

System info through Neofetch:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 
Host: 81DE Lenovo ideapad 330-15IKB 
Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic 
Uptime: 12 hours, 20 mins 
Packages: 3194 (dpkg), 4 (flatpak), 
Shell: bash 5.0.3 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 3.34.1 
WM: GNOME Shell 
WM Theme: Flat-Remix-Dark-fullPanel 
Theme: Flat-Remix-GTK-Blue-Dark [GT 
Icons: Tela-blue [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i5-8250U (6) @ 1.600GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 /  
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
Memory: 3117MiB / 7869MiB
```

**Issue:**
While copying any file to any other location ubuntu starts freezing after 5-6 secs and stutters until file is being copied, this same thing also happens while extracting files from archive. Is it common to everyone ? If not what should i do to fix it ?

> Here is output from fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 24.95 MiB, 26140672 bytes, 51056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 54.66 MiB, 57294848 bytes, 111904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 48.3 MiB, 50642944 bytes, 98912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 54.97 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 44.9 MiB, 47063040 bytes, 91920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 24.9 MiB, 26091520 bytes, 50960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.76 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000LM007-1R81
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3127693A-F345-48A1-A00B-4939AB5723CF

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     1261568 1546811391 1545549824   737G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  1546811392 1562812415   16001024   7.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda3     1228800    1261567      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4        2048    1228799    1226752   599M EFI System
/dev/sda5  1562812416 2851207167 1288394752 614.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  3712591872 3907028991  194437120  92.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  3026987008 3712591871  685604864 326.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  2909800448 3026987007  117186560  55.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  2851207168 2909800447   58593280    28G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/loop8: 93.8 MiB, 98336768 bytes, 192064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 14.77 MiB, 15466496 bytes, 30208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 160.16 MiB, 167931904 bytes, 327992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 91.38 MiB, 95805440 bytes, 187120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 156.7 MiB, 164290560 bytes, 320880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Have you checked the health of your drive (ssd/hdd) using SMART tools? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  Particularly if you've a cheaper device (with long warranty) they tend to slow down to get around issues without report thus avoiding warranty claims, but its still detectable with drives on-board SMART

Comment: @guiverc i tried to run a short test it passed without any errors should i go on testing long too which is a 5 hr test ?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of reading the error stats; number of errs, are they growing since you last looked, increasing faster since you noticed it slowing down etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got fixed after Ubuntu 20.04 update